# FileMaker import into container field from oracle db via ODBC

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, filemaker

Using FM13 want to import jpgs from oracle blob into FM container field.  Want to automate using SQL and ODBC.  Currently export image from oracle and import into FM.  Would like to go more directly from db to db.

Comment: another 360Works product that can automate this process is [MirrrorSync](http://360works.com/mirrorsync)

Answer (score 2):

Direct import is not supported by FileMaker.  See [FileMaker Dataypes and Field Mapping](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6425/~/datatypes-and-field-mapping-with-filemaker)

But you can use the [360Works JDBC plugin](http://360works.com/jdbc-plugin/) to do it because it does support reading and writing container/BLOB data to other databases.